# What does this definition of the upper and lower integral mean?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I'm struggling to understand this definition for a class project on Riemann integration.

Let $\mathcal{P}$ represent all possible partitions over $[a,b]$, where $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, then the upper integral of $f$ is given by $U(f)=$ inf$(\{U(f,P):P\in\mathcal{P}\})$ and the lower integral of $f$ is given by $L(f)=$ sup$(\{L(f,P):P\in\mathcal{P}\})$.

I understand what it's saying, but I have no idea how to apply this. The example I'm illustrating is $f(x)=x$ over the interval $[0,2]$ with four subintervals split off by halves.

I calculated the lower sum as 1.5 and the upper sum as 2.5 by summation. The kicker here is Abbott chose to use the concepts of infimum and supremum with the Axiom of Completeness rather than Riemann sums and limits (so I'm really lost since I'm only familiar with the latter method).

How do I determine the upper and lower integrals for this function?

Comment: By trying all possible partitions :-)

Comment: What does that mean? Do I have to consider all values of n from $1$ to $\infty$? If so, how does that fit into Abbott's definition of sums without using limits?

Comment: No, you must consider all uncountably many partitions ! (In fact you have to find arguments to "handle" all partitions.)

Comment: I'm sorry, that's not helpful. I really am *that* clueless.

Comment: Try with $f(x)=x$, defining an arbitrary partition of $[a,b]$ (say $n$ unequal subintervals).

Comment: Look, I'm not a machine learner or software expert: I'm a musician trying to get a math degree. I'm sorry, but I don't know.

Comment: It's confusing that your question is titled "what does this definition mean", yet you say "I understand what it's saying"

Comment: Er, there is no machine learning nor programming here !? Which words don't you understand ?

Comment: I was referencing your profile. I don't have six-figure reputation on this site, so I'm sorry this isn't as obvious to me as it is to you. I don't see how I'm suppose to find the supremum or infimum of these sets for my example or in general. I don't know why the author is using infimum and supremum rather than the standard infinite limit, nor am sure how to determine these for the given sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to all this is to find a sequence of partitions $P_n$ for which $\lim_{n \to \infty} L(f,P_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty}U(f,P_n) = L$.  If you do this, then we can say that
$$
L = \lim_{n \to \infty} L(f,P_n) \leq \sup_{P \in \mathcal P} L(f,P) \leq \inf_{P \in \mathcal P} U(f,P) \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} U(f,P_n) = L,
$$
which means that these four quantities must all be the same.

In fact, you should find that if you take any "common sense" choice of $P_n$ (e.g. breaking the interval into $n$ equal subintervals), then these two limits are indeed equal. All the "math" that needs to be done here is straightforward; the trick from there is to just use the argument I present to say that $L(f) = U(f) = 2$.

TL;DR: use the usual "Riemann sums and limits" method (for both the "upper" and "lower" sums), but provide a logical argument that this leads to the correct answer.

Comment: Very smart approach +1. At least it works for Riemann integrable functions.